# How to make LINQ query with Unions more efficient

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, query-performance

I inherited the LINQ query below and I feel that the query can be refactored for efficiency.  The query currently takes about 6-8 seconds of processing time to return one record to the user on the front-end of the application.  LINQ is not my strong suite, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

The query should ultimately produce a distinct list of CA_TASK_VW objects that are tied to a list of distinct CA_OBJECT_ID's obtained from the CA_OBJECT, CA_PEOPLE, and CA_CONTRACTOR tables.

```
var data = (from a in _db.CA_TASK_VW
                    where a.TASK_TYPE == "INSPECTION" && a.TASK_AVAILABLE_FLAG == "Y" && a.TARGET_END_DATE == null
                    select a).AsQueryable();

data = data.Join(_db.CA_OBJECT.Where(o => o.ENTERED_BY == _userId),
                o => o.CA_OBJECT_ID, p => p.CA_OBJECT_ID,
                (t, p) => t)
            .Union(data.Join(_db.CA_PEOPLE.Where(p => p.EMAIL == _email),
                t => t.CA_OBJECT_ID, p => p.CA_OBJECT_ID,
                (t, p) => t))
            .Union(data.Join(_db.CA_CONTRACTOR.Where(c => c.CONTRACTOR.EMAIL == _email),
                t => t.CA_OBJECT_ID, c => c.CA_OBJECT_ID,
                (t, c) => t));
```

Comment: You probably should tag the related db engine.

Comment: Tagged SQL as the db engine.

Comment: Have you ran ran the generated SQL in SSMS, analyzed the execution plan, checked statistics? This should tell you if your missing any indexes.

Comment: I don't think indexing is the issue here and I do not have rights to apply indexing to the tables anyway.  The issue here is the logic.  These are huge tables with tens of thousands of records.  I'm looking for a more efficient way to gather the data.  The first glaring issue is the dev who wrote the code starts off by getting every CA_TASK_VW record when the list of CA_OBJECT.CA_OBJECT_ID's should be obtained first to cut down on the results returned from CA_TASK_VW.

Comment: If you want efficiency, then write the raw SQL queries yourself. This is the approach Dapper is using. Entity Framework also supports raw queries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql

Comment: If you are going to write a raw query I would get it working first in SSMS.

Comment: As previously mentioned you should write this query directly in sql because Linq and ORMs like EF are not optimized for large data reads.. For instance SSRS use stored procedures or views..

Comment: SQL isn't a db engine :) - did you mean MS SQL Server? The `AsQueryable()` shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: NOTE: `data` doesn't contain any results, so cutting down to IDs would not help - it is just a sub-query for the main query, it does not query / return any results to the program.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "that are tied to a list of distinct CA_OBJECT_ID" - that isn't happening in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to be using `Join`/`Union` to execute basically a where predicate on the list of `CA_TASK_VW`, filtering it step by step to the final result, so what happens if you just specify the where condition directly?

```
var data = from a in _db.CA_TASK_VW
           where a.TASK_TYPE == "INSPECTION" && a.TASK_AVAILABLE_FLAG == "Y" && a.TARGET_END_DATE == null
           select a;

data = data.Where(t => _db.CA_OBJECT.Where(o => o.ENTERED_BY == _userId).Select(o => o.CA_OBJECT_ID).Contains(t.CA_OBJECT_ID) ||
                       _db.CA_PEOPLE.Where(p => p.EMAIL == _email).Select(p => p.CA_OBJECT_ID).Contains(t.CA_OBJECT_ID) ||
                       _db.CA_CONTRACTOR.Where(c => c.CONTRACTOR.EMAIL == _email).Select(c => c.CA_OBJECT_ID).Contains(t.CA_OBJECT_ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using UNION ALL if you don`t really care about duplicates in your query results as it works much faster than UNION

Comment: Unfortunately I need a list of distinct CA_OBJECT.CA_OBJECT_ID's to obtain a distinct list of CA_TASK_VW objects.